# parser error on my registration form

Tags: php

I'm new to php, creating a registration form and getting

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'
```

on line 6. This works well on my xampp local server when uploaded to Cpanel is when I get the error.

```
<?php
   include ('connection.php');
   if(isset($_POST['submitform'])){
      $name = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']));
      $email = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']));
      $passwords = trim(mysql_escape_string(($_POST['pwd']));
      $password = md5($passwords);
   }
?>
```

I'm using php 5.4 on my local Server

Comment: check line 6 and just remove one "(" bracket from line 6.

Comment: *Please* practice indentation

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Answer (score 1):

change this line ;

```
$passwords = trim(mysql_escape_string(($_POST['pwd']));
```

to

```
$passwords = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST['pwd']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Parser error is solved

```
<?php
include ('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['submitform'])){
$name = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']));
$email = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']));
$passwords = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST['pwd']));
$password = md5($passwords);
}
```

Comment: `$passwords = trim(mysql_escape_string($_POST['pwd']));` this line has the change